# Wrong profile image shown in Jobs

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-picture

I just happened to see this in Jobs and I was surprised:

[image: blue identicon with message saying I need to set up my profile]

This identicon isn’t my profile pic or the image shown under identicon if I go to edit my profile (more [context on my choice of profile image here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283643/323179)).

But I do recognize it. It’s the image I get in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/23020/laurel) (and Area51) when I log in, which generates the image insecurely, IIRC.

The image here should be my profile image, not an image I wouldn’t have ever seen on Stack Overflow.